# Issues setting UIEdgeInsetsMake for UNEVEN image

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need HELP setting up resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake for an UNEVEN image. I have used this successfully with EVEN images, it works fine but having lot of difficulty setting correct values for a particular image. I have a callout bubble image (attached) of size 49 X 158 and using following values for resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake:

```
dialogueBubbleImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"BubbleBottomRightLong_1.png"]
                                   resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 23, 138, 23)];//49 × 158. UIEdgeInsetsMake: CGFloat top, left, bottom, right;
```

Whole idea is to display a label with text inside the white box area, keeping the callout arrow as-is.

Here is the image I am using:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what exactly is the problem? your value for top is too high, you are leaving a 0px vertical area to tile. ideally you would have a single pixel left to tile, so i would choose values like:

```
dialogueBubbleImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"BubbleBottomRightLong_1.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 24, 145, 24)];
```

Comment: i'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to determine the values to pass into UIEdgeInsetsMake based on the image size. can you explain how you figured out what values you thought would work best? thanks